# Вводятся некоторые числа вещественного типа. вывести их в обратном порядке

Tags: c++, c++11, рекурсия, стек

Как сделать так чтобы ноль не выводился , когда числа уже выстраиваются в обратном порядке?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void foo() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    if (n == 0) {
        cout << "Числа в обратном прядке:";
        cout << "\n" << n << " ";
        return;
    }
    foo();
    cout << n << " ";
}


int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    // Реализация по принципу стека, последний зашел - первый вышел, 
    //то есть задача которая помещена в стек самой последней выполняется 
     //   самой первой.
    cout << "Вводимые числа:" << endl;
    foo();
    cout << endl;
system ("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> cout << "\n" << n << " ";
> ```

Удали.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/269000)

Comment: @AndrioSkur, и почему же не является?

Comment: Более точно бы было заменить строку  `cout << "\n" << n << " ";` в `if` на  `cout << "\n";`

Comment: @Темкатоже, пожалуй, да, не заметил, что там перевод строки не выводится.

Answer (score 0):

Удалите вывод `n` (и последовательного пробеля) в комманде

```
cout << "\n" << n << " ";
```

- пишите только

```
cout << "\n";
```

Или - более красиво, `\n` прибавите прямо до предыдущей команды:

(и следующую совсем удалите).

```
cout << "Числа в обратном прядке:\n";
```